# Find element by inner element text using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to click an element by the text of a span who is the child of the element. How do I do this?

```
<button type="button" class="alert-button ion-focusable ion-activatable sc-ion-alert-md" tabindex="0"><span class="alert-button-inner sc-ion-alert-md">OK</span><ion-ripple-effect class="sc-ion-alert-md md hydrated" role="presentation"></ion-ripple-effect></button>
```

This is what I have tried but it didn't work.

```
@FindBy(css = "button[span:contains('OK')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium doesn't supports the *`:contains`* pseudo-class anymore as `@jari.bakken` in their [comment](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/987#issuecomment-191440998) confirms:

> *AFAICT, the :contains pseudo-class isn't in the CSS spec and is not supported by either Firefox or Chrome (even outside WebDriver).*

Further `@dawagner` in their [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1547#issuecomment-191463995) also mentions:

> contains isn't a valid CSS3 selector; because of this several browsers don't natively support contains, so Selenium (and WebDriver) don't claim to support it._

---

### Solution

However you can still use the other attributes to construct a *CssSelector* to identify the element as follows:

```
@FindBy(css = "button.alert-button.ion-focusable.ion-activatable.sc-ion-alert-md span.alert-button-inner.sc-ion-alert-md")
```

As an alternative you can also use either of the following *Xpath* based locator strategies:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@class='alert-button ion-focusable ion-activatable sc-ion-alert-md']//span[@class='alert-button-inner sc-ion-alert-md']")
```

Using the *`innerText`*:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@class='alert-button ion-focusable ion-activatable sc-ion-alert-md']//span[@class='alert-button-inner sc-ion-alert-md' and text()='OK']")
```

or even:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class='alert-button-inner sc-ion-alert-md' and text()='OK']")
```

even possibly:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[text()='OK']")
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Selectors with Selenium **do not** support locating elements by their text content. Only XPath supports that.
Try this XPath:

```
//button//span[text()='OK']
```

or

```
//button//span[contains(.,'OK')]
```

or

```
//button//span[contains(text(),'OK')]
```

So the element could be defined as following

```
@FindBy(xpath= "//button//span[text()='OK']")
```

Or

```
@FindBy(xpath= "//button//span[contains(.,'OK')]")
```